# Folder security with Akamai

Tags: cookies, akamai

Is it possible to create folder-level security through Akamai?  I'd like to secure a folder to a small group of people, but still have it cache in Akamai.

Also, it would be great if I could do this programmatically.  I know that you can purge your cache using their services, but I can't find any documentation on anything else that might be available.

Thanks.

Comment: What exactly do you mean with "folder-level" security and what do you want to do "programmatically"? The first bit of your question is definitely possible.

Comment: So I have "/myfolder/mysecuredfolder/item.aspx".  I'd like to have the contents of "/mysecuredfolder/" only readable by a specific set of users.  Also, I'd like to be able to assign users read permission to this folder programmatically.  I looked for an API for this, but was unable to find one.        Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can read [here](http://www.akamai.com/dl/feature_sheets/FS_edgesuite_accesscontrol.pdf) about several ways to implement access control via Akamai, i.e. when requesting `/myfolder/mysecuredfolder/*` Akamai will then ask to your server if a user can go there. 
The "programmatic read permission" is then implemented at your origin.
Further optimization to minimize the number of times Akamai needs to ask you whether a user can read a specific folder can be achieved combining the above auth on the edge with cookies.